# Cannot see hardware security token on my Windows PC

Tags: windows-10, smartcard, token

I have a SafeNet Token JC device that provides a certificate when I am connecting to a VPN using CheckPoint VPN Client.

I'm facing an issue that CheckPoint cannot see that device. I have Windows 10 and it worked almost a month without a problem. Last week I noticed I cannot connect to VPN anymore.

It says I should connect the smart card, but it is already connected.

[image]

I can see smart card device:

*ex. Device Manager*

[image: device manager screenshot]

I can see lot of errors in EventLog:

```
Error   21.01.2020 20:49:35 WudfUsbccidDrv  7   Driver

    <EventData>
      <Data Name="Name">ReaderCompletionUnknownMsgType</Data> 
      <Data Name="Value">0x0</Data> 
    </EventData>
```

On other PC or even in VirtualBox on same PC on virtualized Windows 10 I can connect using the device and checkpoint without any problem.

Interesting is that I can see one more device on the other PC or virtualized computer - `Smart Card - SafeNet Minidriver`:

*ex. Device Manager - Other PC*

[image: device manager on other pc with one more device]

On my PC there must be some application/driver that blocks the device. But I can not figure out what is it.

Comment: If you log into a new user account does it work?  If you remove the device, and choose the option to delete the driver, and once you have installed the driver again does the device continue the behavior you describe?

Comment: Yes I tried both (new admin user account and delete driver and install again) with same results :(

Comment: Did you try plugging the device into a different USB port

Comment: Yes, also same results

Comment: I have the same problem as you, and I am searching for a solution for months.  In my investigation, this problem started with Windows 10 1903 update, so maybe you got this update recently (run winver.exe to check your version).  Apparently, this problem does not affect new Windows installations, but it affects not-so-new ones.  My CA confirms this problem exists and that several users are experiencing it, but they do not know how to solve.  Their only workaround is to reinstall the OS (format) or use other computer.

Comment: Are you by any chance connection to the computer via Remote Desktop? I had very similar problem until I connected via command line (winrs -r:myserver.mydomain cmd) and suddenly the token was recognized

Answer (score 2):

Had very similar problem, SafeNet Authentication Client was not seeing my SafeNet USB Token. The issue was I was connecting via RDP. When I logged in directly on the machine, it started working.
According to [this MS Blog Explanation](http://web.archive.org/web/20150922133959/http://blogs.technet.com/b/instan/archive/2011/03/27/why-can-t-i-see-my-local-smartcard-readers-when-i-connect-via-rdp.aspx) :

> if you RDP into a session from the start you will never see any local
> smartcard readers as Winscard will detect it’s running in an RDP
> session and no calls to Winscard will ever reach the local PC/SC layer
> – everything will be redirected to the connecting client

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).